# Can't use parsed fields to visualize data on kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, kibana-4, filebeat

I'm new in this ELK stuff. I've been trying to create visualizations using this stack, but I'm not able to use fields such as **verb**, **response**, **request**, **etc**, I'm only able to select [a few available fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3zFM.png):

However, in the Discover section I'm perfectly able to work with those fields. Here is a sample of one of my query results:

(I'm using Kibana 4.4.2, filebeat forwarding to logstash 2.2.3)

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-2016.04.12",
  "_type": "apache_log",
  "_id": "AVQMoRFwO5HM5nz1lmXf",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "187.142.15.173 - - [12/Apr/2016:16:39:23 -0600] \"GET /v1.0/person/297312123/client/1132347/profile HTTP/1.1\" 200 2051 \"-\" \"Android CEX 2.2.0\"",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-04-12T22:39:27.064Z",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "myhost",
      "name": "myhost"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "fields": null,
    "input_type": "log",
    "offset": 30034512,
    "source": "/var/log/httpd/access_log",
    "type": "apache_log",
    "host": "myhost",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "clientip": "187.142.15.173",
    "ident": "-",
    "auth": "-",
    "timestamp": "12/Apr/2016:16:39:23 -0600",
    "verb": "GET",
    "request": "/v1.0/person/297312123/client/1132347/profile",
    "httpversion": "1.1",
    "response": "200",
    "bytes": "2051",
    "referrer": "\"-\"",
    "agent": "\"Android CEX 2.2.0\"",
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1460500767064
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1460500767064
  ]
}
```

**What could posibly be wrong with this?**

**Here is my config file:**

```
   filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {         
        grok {
            match => { "message" => 
              "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"
        }
        add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
        add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }

    syslog_pri { }

    date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
    if [type] == "apache_log" {

        grok {
        # match => [ "message", "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" ]
            # match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
            # add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
            # add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
        match => [ "message", "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" ]
        }

        #syslog_pri { }

        #date {
        #    match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        #}

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be the kibana field cache.  Go to Settings->Indexes, select your index, and click the orange Reload button.